# Auto add script doesn't work with Facebook latest design

Tags: javascript, facebook

I tried the Auto-add script that adds your Facebook friends automatically to a group. Unfortunately it does't work for me as I have the newest design. (Script worked with my brother's account and he doesn't have the new design).

When I type in the code below :

```
javascript:(function()
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://aldaryen.googlecode.com/files/da.js';
})();
```

I get the following in FF developer console :

`Type Error : Env undefined`

So I guess there are some modifications to be made to the script, however I am not a JavaScript adept (I've recently mastered C programming though, I don't if that helps).

**PS :** I tried different source codes from different websites, and also a chrome plugin. Nothing works for my account but works in my brother's account so the culprit is definitely the new design.

My question is : how to adapt it to work for the new design?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. But instead of modifying the JS code, I found a way to go back to Facebook old design. It's a Chrome Plugin called User-Agent Switcher that enables you to display your page as if it was opened by another Browser. (Something like old IE-Tab). And in the list of choices I chose to display my facebook page in IE6. And since the new design is not supported in IE6, the display automatically went back to the old design. And I was able to make the JS Code work.